# How to provide multiple search base in ping federate?

Tags: openldap, pingfederate

I have multiple DIT in LDAP. `(dc=example,dc=com and dc=test,dc=com)`. Under create credential validator instance, I am not able to give more than one search base. I tried to give SEARCH BASE:

```
dc=example,dc=com dc=test,dc=com
dc=example,dc=com : dc=test,dc=com
dc=example,dc=com ; dc=test,dc=com
dc=example,dc=com | dc=test,dc=com
```

Should I try any other combinations?

Note : Connecting to multiple datastores can be accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

You can't support multiple LDAP Suffix from a single PingFederate Data Source or Password Credential Validator. I would create a single Data Source and then create a single PCV for each suffix you wish to search. If you are using the HTML Form Adapter, you can then use multiple PCV when attempting to authenticate a user's identity.